# How to solve ' Selenium StaleElementReferenceException , the element seems to be disconnected from the DOM. '?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a JSF2 application with Selenium, but getting  a lot of StaleElementReferenceExceptions and don't know how to solve these issues. The Selenium documentation tells me, that the objects are no longer in the DOM anymore and you have to reattach them.How can I do this?

The exceptions are thrown on pages where a javascript updates content dynamically. The strange thing is that sometimes the tests are successfull and sometimes they fail, thus not having deterministic behaviour.

I'm using the HTMLUnitDriver( WebDriver ) for the test. I also tried the ChromeDriver and Chrome is running correctly through the tests. But Chrome is not usable on a Jenkins CI build.

Here is an example trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element seems to be disconnected from the DOM.  This means that a user cannot interact with it.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.16.1', revision: '15405', time: '2012-01-05 12:30:12'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_29'
Driver info: driver.version: SenderPageDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.assertElementNotStale(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:854)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.getTagName(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:360)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.switchFocusToThisIfNeeded(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:316)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:345)
    at ch.postlogistics.avg.common.AbstractPageDriver.fillInTextField(AbstractPageDriver.java:140)
    at ch.postlogistics.avg.common.SenderPageDriver.senderCompany(SenderPageDriver.java:73)
    at ch.postlogistics.avg.common.SenderPageDriver.addSender(SenderPageDriver.java:122)
    at ch.postlogistics.avg.webtest.parcel.ParcelWorkflowTest.goThroughWorkflowWithLabelGenerationWithVinolog(ParcelWorkflowTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this.   Note that it is possible for this method to return a null .   You can edit this method to suit your needs.  This method can be improved by using FluentWait instead, for example.

```
public static WebElement getElementByLocator( By locator ) {
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 9, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  WebElement we = null;
  boolean unfound = true;
  int tries = 0;
  while ( unfound && tries < 10 ) {
    tries += 1;
    try {
      we = driver.findElement( locator );
      unfound = false; // FOUND IT
    } catch ( StaleElementReferenceException ser ) {                    
      unfound = true;
    } catch ( NoSuchElementException nse ) {                        
      unfound = true;
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println("Unknown error.");
    }
  } 
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  return we;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing  some wait into your script.The exception can be thrown because you are not waiting for the page to be fully loaded.